# When studying moderations: Do you build a separate model for each moderation or include them all in one model?

Tags: interaction, panel-data

I have a panel dataset and build a negative binomial regression model for it.

Here I would like to test a total of three interactions. So, if I include all three moderations (thus also the independent variables) and the control variables in my model, I get significant P-values for the moderations.  But if I have each moderation in a single model (contoll variable stays the same only interaction x2 * x3 drops out), the p-values are no longer significant.

What does that tell me? And is it at all common to put all moderations in one model?

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to include all predictors and interactions in a single full model, if you can do so without overfitting. Otherwise you run a risk of [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias). If there are particular comparisons you want to make based on individual values of predictors, make them from the full model.

Your observation of the difference in the two approaches illustrates why this is important: when you control for other variables associated with outcome, the significance of a particular variable of interest can become more evident.